# networking restart throws error

Tags: networking, debian

System: Debain Squeeze

Problem: cannot restart networking (`/etc/init.d/networking restart`) without error.

I used and edited a [sample configuration](http://paste.jdsv.de/view/20d44149) from my provider and now wanted to add IPv6 support. But before adding v6 I'd like to get rid of the following error:

```
# /etc/init.d/networking restart
Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces ... (warning).
Reconfiguring network interfaces...SIOCADDRT: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
done.
```

Any suggestions?

**update**

```
# ip r l
x.y.132.64/26 via x.y.132.65 dev eth0 
x.y.132.64/26 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src x.y.132.68 
192.168.1.0/24 dev vboxnet0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1 
default via x.y.132.65 dev eth0
```

btw: Networking works just fine - I can reach the server and from the server I can reach the internet. Only `networking restart` is not satisfied.

Comment: `cat /etc/network/interfaces`? `cat /etc/init.d/networking`?

Comment: At the moment -> see the posted sample configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The "gateway" line already adds the default route. The "up route ..." and "down route ..." lines are unnecessary.

As the "gateway" line already adds the default route, a second attempt at the "up ..." line fails with the given error.

Comment: Thanks, but removing the two routes (or the gateway) has no effect and the error remains.

Comment: try a `../networking stop; ../networking start` ?

Answer (score 1):

The `SIOCADDRT: File exists` error is generally caused by trying to add a route that already exists when you restart networking services:

From [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/siocaddrt-file-exists-ubuntu-linux-error-solution/):

```
Understanding SIOCADDRT: File exists Message

SIOC: Serial Input Output Controller.
ADD: ADD (addition).
RT: RouTe (routing ip).
File exists - Routing is already configured so delete wrong one and add the new one.
```

As @hayalci mentioned you need to remove either the gateway or the up-route/down-route directives. It's likely that this did not fix your issue because the route had *already* been added. Check the output of `ip route show` and if you have multiple routes for that IP address manually remove them and restart networking.

You should also confirm that you don't have any network auto configuration utilities like NetworkManager or WicD running.